# Angular 5 with HttpClient not returning HttpHeaders in error response

Tags: angular, rest

I'm trying to examine the HttpHeaders from a 401 response to see if the auth token needs refreshed however the the HttpHeaders object in the error has nothing inside am I doing something wrong or is this a bug since I can see the header in chrome's console window:

```
get Header() {
   let headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers = headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.authService.accessToken}`);
   const options: any = { headers: headers, observe: 'response'};

   return options;
} 
Observable.interval(this.interval)
    .switchMap(() => this.http.get(this.Url, this.Header).take(1))
    .subscribe(
      (data) => { console.log('got data'); },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err.headers));
      }
    );
```

here's the console log from the error:

```
{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}}
```

and here's the response headers as captured from chrome

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Kestrel
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The access token is no longer valid."
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:70b5c92d-7561-44ce-ade9-dcf9c4bd6372
X-Correlation-Id: 0HLA7HBHN01NA:0000003E
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 20 Dec 2017 10:43:13 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Note that including the code that suggests it as a duplicate does not resolve the problem

Comment: The Back end server is soley responsible for returning an error code and an  error message. If one is missing, you will have to throw a error message from your backend. Without knowing what you are using I cant help you further.

Comment: What is in `this.Header` variable?

Comment: I know the backend is responsible for returning the error code as was stated its the http headers I want from the error. I've included the code for the header, and updated it with the observe: 'response' which doesn't make any difference to the error headers